# can i change the black background of an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

My app is structured like this, a single MainWindow with window backgroundColor to white(which doesn't appear anywhere anyway), and in this nib i have a UINavigationController which doesn't seems to have a backgroundColor.
Any view controller is added from code and made from code and they have a gray background.
What happens is that when i rotate the iphone and the views are rotating as well, i see a black background under my views. Can this be changed? It looks ugly especially if i have a photo that is rotating in the same time with my gray background.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the embedded view in the UINavigationView

When you are your UINavigationview Class :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greyColor];
```

Or any other color you want.

Comment: Thanks for your time but is not that, the background is still black. i tried: window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; and navController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; Maybe i can make the view large enough that i can't see behind it when rotating.

Comment: It means that there is something wrong with your implementation, could you post some code so we can help you more ? Are you using IB ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `backgroundColor` of `UIWindow` in the file 'MainWindow.xib'